# ros node does not change its name after restart

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

actually I'm working on a c++ s-function in Matlab Simulink that is able to comunicate to ros. Therefore I initialize the ros node once by

ros::int(argc, argv, nodeName);

and terminate the node by

ros::shutdown();

Therewith I can create and destroy a ros node.

The issue I have with this is, that after once starting and ending a simulink model, the ros node name can't be changed. Even by starting another model the node name is not changed. I tried changing nodeName and also the command line arguments argc and argv ( __name:=NodeName ). It only changes after a recompile of the s-function or by a restart of matlab. What can I do with this?

Many thanks for your answers in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11026/ros-node-does-not-change-its-name-after-restart/) by [2_socke](https://answers.ros.org/users/996/2_socke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yeah that's a matlab problem.
matlab caches the s-funtions

there is a brutal way by running:

- clear all

or just unload every single s-function by using

- clear fun s-function_name

cheers

---

Originally posted by [mrfloflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/997/mrfloflo/) with karma: 26 on 2011-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1